# Domain name required for sender address

Tags: email, postfix, ubuntu-12.04

I'm trying to setup postfix on a new vps I just got and this is the first time doing any kind of email setup. I am getting an error when trying to perform a test email. I posted my config and error and I'm wondering if I made a mistake somewhere? I'm running a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VPS.

Getting error:

```
mail from:<jhvisser>
250 2.1.0 <jhvisser>... Sender ok
rcpt to:<jhvisser>
553 5.5.4 <jhvisser>... Domain name required for sender address jhvisser
```

With config:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = yes

# Uncomment the next line to geneAug 23 10:15:36 jhvisser sm-mta[15093]: r7NEExQ1015093: from=<jhvisser@jhvisser.com>, size=5, class=0, nrcpts=1, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
```

Aug 23 10:15:36 jhvisser sm-mta[15093]: r7NEExQ1015093: from=, size=5, class=0, nrcpts=1, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
rate "delayed mail" warnings
    #delay_warning_time = 4h

```
readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = jhvisser.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = jhvisser.com
mydestination = jhvisser.com, localhost.com, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = 
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = 
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

New Error:

```
helo localhost
250 jhvisser.com Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
mail from:<jhvisser@jhvisser.com>
250 2.1.0 <jhvisser@jhvisser.com>... Sender ok
rcpt to:<jhvisser@jhvisser.com>
250 2.1.5 <jhvisser@jhvisser.com>... Recipient ok
data
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
test
.
421 4.3.0 collect: Cannot write ./dfr7NDpBPF014521 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=112): No such file or directory
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Log:

```
Aug 23 10:15:36 jhvisser sm-mta[15093]: r7NEExQ1015093: from=<jhvisser@jhvisser.com>, size=5, class=0, nrcpts=1, proto=SMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
```

Comment: sm-mta it seems sendmail instead of postfix. Are you sure that you are using postfix?

Comment: @ALex_hha I followed this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix . Should be postfix?

Comment: Should be, but "Hello localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you" it's not typical postfix greetings. I will suggest to stop postfix and run # netstat -lanp | grep 25 or # lsof -i tcp:25 to see who exactly are listening on the port

Comment: @ALex_hha Is there a good tutorial you know of to setup email on a Ubuntu server or a easier software? I essentially just want to be able to use SMTP so I can send and receive emails using Gmail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`postconf -n | grep reject` and see the parameter "smtpd_sender_restrictions" : check if there is "reject_non_fqdn_sender".

in fact, you should use "jhvisser@jhvisser.com" as sender adress because the destination user can't respond to you if there is a problem.

Comment: I did what you said and changed both the to and from to use that in my tests and now they are okay but I have a new problem. Check my edit to see the new problem

Comment: Strange ! Check the logs : there is maybe a problem with your spool dir.

Comment: Logs added to OP.

Comment: sm-mta in the logs ?? it is sendmail not postfix. Check if you are running postfix like Alex_hha said, please